# Why is a Trusted Execution Environment more significant for mobile devices?

Tags: security

I've been trying to understand what a Trusted Execution Environment is and how they work. Why is there such a strong emphasis on mobile devices? I've been trying to look for what's the difference in personal computers versus mobile devices with respect to a TEE. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it’s late; I will add my comments in simplest possible way for reference.

As the world starts to move toward *Enterprise Mobility*, using mobile devices for work starts to become essential for different companies and organizations. From there a need come up to secure that devices, not only the data, but the processes and memory allocation as well; Especially when governments and sensitive departments start to use mobile devices.

Starting from the very low level of mobile devices architecture, every mobile device has a processor, processor manufacturers come up with new technology which creates two isolated areas running at the same time (e.g. ARM Trustzone) on the CPU and controlled by SoC (Software on Chip).

First area is where everyone use on mobile devices (Normal World / Rich Execution Environment - **REE**), the second one is the secure area (Secure World / Trusted Execution Environment - **TEE**). Each area has its own operating system running at the same CPU but their processes and memory allocation are totally separate.

Many mobile device manufactures (e.g Samsung), start to utilize that area, by loading third party secure Operating System (OS) into there (e.g Kinibi OS from Trustonic).
Developing applications (Trusted Application - TA) in the secure world is not easy process, provisioning them there is another story and integrating that applications with the normal world is another story as well (Some sort of especial SDK provided by TEE OS owner has to be used).

It is worth to mentioning that applications running in the TEE can have extraordinary privileges and normally TEE OS Owners limit what TA’s can do.

Lastly, although TEE is considered a secure area for sensitive processes (So far). There are other ways to achieve same level (or even better) of security on mobile devices.